# Is it possible to initialize Kotlin instance variables before constructor like in Java

Tags: java, kotlin, initialization

In Java the `name` is initialized before the constructor:

```
 public class Cat1 {
    String name = "Name";

    public Cat1() {
        System.out.println(name);  //prints " Name"
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Cat1();
    }
}
```

Is there a similar code in Kotlin? Can we initialize an instance variable before the constructor?

Comment: Fairly sure in Java `String name = "Name"` will actually be run _in_ the Java constructor if you inspect the byte code.  I am not familiar with Kotlin but it seems like `init` may be similar in the way that it works.

Comment: By "before", do you mean written on a higher line in your file, or *executed* earlier in time? The second is not exactly true in your Java code above. `name` is initialized after the implicit super-constructor call that is first called inside your constructor.

Comment: executed earlier in time than the constructor of Cat1 class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to be clear about what we're talking about, in your Java example, the member variables are getting initialized here:

```java
public class Cat1 {
    String name = "Name";

    public Cat1() {
        // super(); <-- Implicit when you omit it
        // name gets initialized at this point of time during constructor call.
        System.out.println(name); 
    }
}
```

So it's not initialized before the constructor, but it's initialized immediately following the super-constructor call.

In Kotlin, you have both property initializations and `init` blocks that are called *after* the initialization of any properties in the *primary* constructor, but before the code in the blocks of any *secondary* constructors.

Property initializations and `init` blocks are called in order from top to bottom.

So the simplest way to duplicate your class example is to use a primary constructor and an `init` block after your property:

```kotlin
public class Cat1() { 
    var name: String = "Name"

    init {
        println(name)
    }
}
```

Note, parentheses for the primary constructor are optional if it has no parameters and there are no secondary constructors.

If you have a secondary constructor, your properties will initialized before its block of code:

```kotlin
public class Cat1 { 
    var name: String = "Name"

    constructor() {
        println(name)
    }
}
```

...even if they are declared later (just like in Java):

```kotlin
public class Cat1 { 
    constructor() {
        println(name)
    }

    var name: String = "Name"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to initialize Kotlin instance variables before constructor like in Java

Yes, it is.

> Is there a similar code in Kotlin?

Yes, it's almost exactly the same. Explained in the documentation:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors

> Can we initialize an instance variable before the constructor?

Yes, you can.

Comment: Could you specify the example? Here class InitOrderDemo(name: String) initialization occurs In primary constructor.

Comment: What do you mean "Specify the example?" What is `InitOrderDemo(name: String)`?

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you cannot instantiate a variable before the constructor but you can do something similar.

1.
You can declare a variable without initialising it and then add its value to it in a function. This allows you to add its own functionality to it.
For example:

```
class one {
  lateinit var variable1: String
  
  constructor(){}
  
  fun play() {
    variable1 = "one"
  }
}
```

2. 

You can declare the variable with a null and then assign a value to it in the constructor.
For example:

```
class two(val parameter: Int) {
    var two: String? = null

    init {
        two= "two"
    }
}
```